# discord.py - on_message spam - jump_url

Tags: discord.py

I'm working on a logging bot. To do this I'm using `on_message` with `jump_url` to detect links, however the bot just spams it, I'm guessing this is because it reads its own message.

I have tried to stop it by checking if the message author is the user, however that didn't fix it. Whenever I type anything it logs it and has the link even though I didn't put in any link.

This is in a cog.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message): 
    
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Message from {} contains a link ".format(message.author.name), description="", color=0x607d8b)
    
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/9005083965732483134/14fcc0c2d369d9f4d742d9e8471d8536.webp?size=1024")
    embed.add_field(name="Message:" ,value=message.jump_url, inline=True)
```

The code works; it's just that the bot spams the link. There is some code missing like channel.send as I'm connected to a database to log the channels people picked to log stuff.

Comment: Can you show us the code you used to check if the message is sent by a bot? Maybe you did not make that check correctly. Also do you have the same code for the on_message event in another file? Just throwing out some ideas

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can combat this, I will show you two possible methods to avoid your problem.

**Method 1** involves checking if the author of the message, `message.author`, is a bot through its [attributes](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=author#discord.abc.User). This method ensures that if the user is a bot, then *your* bot will ignore the message.

**Method 2** will only ignore your own bot. You can do this using `self.bot`, which you may have defined in your `__init__`. With this, you can compare if the `message.author` is your bot, and if it's True you may ignore it.

Do view the methods below as explained above.

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        # Method 1
        if message.author.bot:
            return
        # Method 2
        if message.author == self.bot:
            return
        # Please note: You do not need to use both methods!
```